# Upload progress bar for small files in meteor CollectionFS

Tags: javascript, meteor, collectionfs

With the `meteor-cfs-ui`-package you can show a progress bar for uploading files. But this only works well für files, which are bigger then 2 MB. If the files are smaller, the bar just jumps from 0% to 100%.

[Here](http://blog.zipboard.co/2015/11/23/cfs-tips-and-tricks-for-meteorjs/) I found a solution for that, which uses this code:

```
if(fsFile.original.size < (2097152)*10) {
  var chunkSize = fsFile.original.size / 10;
  FS.config.uploadChunkSize = chunkSize;
}
uploadFile(fsFile, fullFileName, projectId);
```

But where do I have to put that code?

I declare my stores like this:

```
Images = new FS.Collection("images", {
    stores: [
        new FS.Store.FileSystem("something", {
            transformWrite: function (fileObj, readStream, writeStream) {
                // do transformations
            }           
        })]
    });
```

The upload is done like this:

```
FS.Utility.eachFile(event, function (file) {
    var newFile = new FS.File(file);
    newFile.uploadedFrom = Meteor.userId();

    data = Images.insert(newFile, function (error, fileObject) {});
});
```

So I guess it is a stupid question, but I really don't see, where to put that code...

Comment: The code looks like it is forcing a chunked upload regardless of size. Why slow down the user's upload for such a small file when you only want to change something about the progress bar?

Comment: Because on a slow connection 2MB can take awhile and without a progress bar the user can think the app has wedged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The upload happens on collection insert so you *should* be able to set the `chunkSize` right before that:

```
FS.Utility.eachFile(event, function (file) {
    var newFile = new FS.File(file);
    newFile.uploadedFrom = Meteor.userId();

    var maxChunk = 2097152;
    FS.config.uploadChunkSize =
      ( newFile.original.size < 10*maxChunk ) ? newFile.original.size/10 : maxChunk;

    data = Images.insert(newFile, function (error, fileObject) {});
});
```

Comment: Also I suggest you set a minimum size, ex: 10KB so that you avoid degenerate cases.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you are using `FS.EventHandlers.insertFiles` and don't see the loading bar, create this function in your client code:

```
/**
 * Replace for original FS.EventHandlers.insertFiles function.
 */
function cfsInsertFiles(collection, options) {
  options = options || {};
  var afterCallback = options.after;
  var metadataCallback = options.metadata;

  function insertFilesHandler(event) {
    FS.Utility.eachFile(event, function (file) {
      var f = new FS.File(file);
      var maxChunk = 2097152;
      FS.config.uploadChunkSize =
        (f.original.size < 10 * maxChunk) ? f.original.size / 10 : maxChunk;
      if (metadataCallback) {
        FS.Utility.extend(f, metadataCallback(f));
      }
      collection.insert(f, afterCallback);
    });
  }

  return insertFilesHandler;
}
```

And finally use it instead `FS.EventHandlers.insertFiles`. For example:

```
Template.files.events({
    'dropped .imageArea': cfsInsertFiles(Images, {
      metadata: function (fileObj) {
        return {
          owner: Meteor.userId(),
          foo: "bar"
        };
      },
      after: function (error, fileObj) {
        console.log("Inserted", fileObj.name);
      }
    })
});
```